# Cannot run compiled java class, error: Class names are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested

Tags: java

Ok, this seems to be a typical error as of discussing a lot in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063266/java-compile-problem-class-names-are-only-accepted-if-annotation-processing-is), however I still don't know what's wrong with my program. I use commmand prompt to compile my java classes.

`TestQueueString.java` is a simple class I create to test my implementation 
of the block representation of queue in `QueueStringBlock.java`. This is how I compile.

```
C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Lab>javac -cp DAT.jar;Exceptions.jar QueueStringBlock.java TestQueueString.java

C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Lab>javac TestQueueString
error: Class names, 'TestQueueString', are only accepted if annotation processing is
explicitly requested 1 error
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

And when I use `java` instead of `javac`, it always asks for main method I guess:

```
C:\Users\TRI\Desktop\Lab>java -cp DAT.jar;Exceptions.jar TestQueueString
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestQueueString
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestQueueString
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: TestQueueString.  Program will exit.
```

Be noticed that it does produce .class files after compiling :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `javac`, the compiler, to **run** your program. You run the program via `java`, not `javac`. Your second command should be:

```
java -cp DAT.jar;Exceptions.jar TestQueueString
```

Note no "c" on "java", and I've added the classpath since you added it when compiling.

---

Re your edit: The problem there is exactly what it says it is: It can't find the class `TestQueueString`. I can think of two possible reasons for this:

1. The current directory is not in your classpath; try:

   ```
   java -cp DAT.jar;Exceptions.jar;. TestQueueString
   ```

   (Note the `;.` at the end of the classpath.)
2. Your `TestQueueString.java` file has a `package` declaration. If so, you need to tell `java` the full name of the class (e.g., `foo.TestQueueString` not just `TestQueueString` if it were in package `foo`), and the file has to be in the right place relative to the current working directory (again assuming package `foo`, the class file would have to be in a `foo` subdirectory).

Given the error message you've quoted, and assuming you're using an up-to-date version of Java, I'd guess #1, since #2 would say something like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestQueueString (wrong name: foo/TestQueueString)
```

...(note the "wrong name" bit) if the package were `foo`.

Comment: It still doesn't help. See my edit above : ) Thanks for answering anyway.

Comment: @Trisism: The edit changes the question. I've edited the answer to reflect the new question.

Comment: T.J.Crowder: "java -cp DAT.jar;Exceptions.jar TestQueueString" causes the same error... ):

Comment: And TestQueueString.java only has a few lines, just a constructor that calls QueueStringBlock's implementations i.e. q.enqueue(), q.dequeue(), etc. It has no package declaration at all.

Comment: @Trisism: Sorry, I had an error in #1 of the edit, I kind of forgot to add `.` to the classpath (which was the whole point of #1). If that's not it, it's clear that you need to post the full contents of `TestQueueString.java` in the question.

Comment: @Trisism: Good deal! Sorry for the editing error earlier. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the Classpath to Dat.jar, and Exception.jar, essentially telling the JVM to look for the .class files in those locations. However, TestQueueString is not in either .jar file. It is in your current directory. Since you told the JVM to look for .class files in the .jars, it does not check your current directory.
Breaking it down step by step, this line:

```
java -cp DAT.jar;Exceptions.jar TestQueueString
```

says: Run a java program, with the main method found in the class TestQueueString, and search for the .class files in Dat.jar and Exceptions.jar.
What you can do is add ".;" to the beginning of your Classpath, which tells the JVM to also search in the current directory.