# Error: "Class names are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested"

Tags: java, compilation, javac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Compile Problem: Class names are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063266/java-compile-problem-class-names-are-only-accepted-if-annotation-processing-is)

I have encountered a problem. I am using crimson editor. Could someone explain what this error means?

// here is my program

```
package test.rim.bbapps.testcase.lib;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class michaeltictactoe2 implements ActionListener {

    /* Instance variables */

    private JFrame window = new JFrame (" TicTacToe");
    private JButton button1 = new JButton ("") ;
    private JButton button2 = new JButton ("") ;
    private JButton button3 = new JButton ("") ;
    private JButton button4 = new JButton ("") ;
    private JButton button5 = new JButton ("") ;
    private JButton button6 = new JButton ("") ;
    private JButton button7 = new JButton ("") ;
    private JButton button8 = new JButton ("") ;
    private JButton button9 = new JButton ("") ;
    private String letter = "";
    private int count = 0; 
    private boolean win = false; 

    public michaeltictactoe2 () {
        //* Create Window * /
        window.setSize (300,300);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLayout ( new GridLayout (3, 3));

        /* Adding buttons to the window*/
        window.add(button1);
        window.add(button2);
        window.add(button3);
        window.add(button4);
        window.add(button5);
        window.add(button6);
        window.add(button7);
        window.add(button8);
        window.add(button9);

        /* Add the action listener to the Button */
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        button3.addActionListener(this);
        button4.addActionListener(this);
        button5.addActionListener(this);
        button6.addActionListener(this);
        button7.addActionListener(this);
        button8.addActionListener(this);
        button9.addActionListener(this);

        //* make the window visible * /
        window.setVisible (true) ;
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent a) {
        count++;

        /* Calculate who's turn it is */
        if (count == 1 || count == 3|| count == 5 || count == 7 || count == 9) {
            letter = "X"; 
        } else if ( count == 2 || count == 4 || count  == 6 || count == 8  ) {
            letter = "O";   
        }

        /* Display X's or O's on the buttons */
        if ( a.getSource () == button1) {
            button1.setText ( letter ) ;
            button1.setEnabled (false);
        } else if (a.getSource () == button2) {
            button2.setText(letter);
            button2.setEnabled(false); 
        } else if (a.getSource () == button3) {
            button3.setText(letter);
            button3.setEnabled(false); 
        } else if (a.getSource () == button4) {
            button4.setText(letter);
            button4.setEnabled(false); 
        } else if (a.getSource () == button5) {
            button5.setText(letter);
            button5.setEnabled(false); 
        } else if (a.getSource () == button6) {
            button6.setText(letter);
            button6.setEnabled(false); 
        } else if (a.getSource () == button7) {
            button7.setText(letter);
            button7.setEnabled(false); 
        } else if (a.getSource () == button8) {
            button8.setText(letter);
            button8.setEnabled(false); 
        } else if (a.getSource () == button9) {
            button9.setText(letter);
            button9.setEnabled(false);
        }

        // * Determine who won */
        // horizontal wins
        if ( button1.getText () == button2.getText ()
            && button2.getText () == button3.getText ()
            && button1.getText () != "") {

            win = true;

        } else if ( button4.getText () == button5.getText ()
                    && button5.getText () == button6.getText ()
                    && button4.getText () != "") {
            win = true;

        } else if ( button7.getText () == button8.getText ()
                &&    button8.getText () == button9.getText ()
                &&    button7.getText () != "") {
                win = true;

            // Verticle wins 
        } else if (button1.getText() == button4.getText ()
               && button4.getText() == button7.getText ()
               && button1.getText() != "") {
               win = true; 

        } else if (button2.getText() == button5.getText()
                &&  button5.getText() == button8.getText()
                &&  button2.getText() != "") {
               win = true;
        } else if ( button3.getText() == button6.getText()
                &&   button6.getText() == button9.getText()
                &&   button9.getText() != "") {
               win = true ;

        // Diagonal wins 
        } else if (button1.getText() == button5.getText()
                && button5.getText() == button9.getText()
                && button1.getText() != "") {
                win = true; 

         } else if (button3.getText() == button5.getText()
                 && button5.getText() == button7.getText()
                 && button3.getText() != "") {
                win = true;
         } else {
                win = false ;
         }

        /* show a dialog is someone wins or the game is tie*/
        if ( win == true) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letter + " YOU WIN!");
        } else if (count == 9 && win == false) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null , " Tie Game!" ) ;  
        }
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        new michaeltictactoe2 () ;
    }
}
```

here is the error

```
---------- Capture Output ----------
> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\javac.exe" michaeltictactoe2
error: Class names, 'michaeltictactoe2', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
1 error

> Terminated with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Seriously though, this question is answered in the first google result for the problem in an FAQ by sun, please try to google this sort of thing before posting

Answer (score 34):

You forgot to include .java in your compile command:

```
javac michaeltictaxtoe2.java
                       ^^^^^ add this
```

Comment: gotta love those brain farts