# Java Code Not Working

Tags: java

This is what the error had displayed:
`Error: Class 'Management' are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested` (What does that mean? also I'm a beginner)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Management {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Start V //

        int Choice;

        // End V //
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome To Siminea Inc Management System ");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("What Would You Like To Find? ");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("(1) Bank");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("(2) Workers");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("(3) Contact Us");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("What Would You Like to Find Out? ");

    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063266/javac-error-class-names-are-only-accepted-if-annotation-processing-is-explicitl

Answer (score 0):

The error means you forget to put `.java` when compiling .Do

`javac Management.java`

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html)

Comment: After compiling how did you run it ,java filename ?

Comment: @AlexS the error means that you might be doing something wrong recheck again

Comment: When I run the system in cmd it just comes up with that error but now I've taken off the Import Scanner thing and now a different error comes up

Comment: @AlexS what is the error can you post it in question

Comment: forget that the same error: Class 'Management' are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested

Comment: @AlexS can you post a picture of your cmd

Comment: I Don't Really Know How To Do That On Here

Comment: @AlexS just use some online tool and give me the link

Comment: @AlexS there is a difference between compiling and running.To compile you do `javac Management.java` (where Management.java is file name) which worked in your case.Now to run you have to do `java Management` (where MAnagement is class name) not `javac Management`

Comment: @singhakash I now tried it with java Management but still same error

Comment: @AlexS can you give the image

Comment: @singhakash My Apologies its a different error but still an error... im so done with java !! Grrr

Comment: @AlexS did you set the environment variable and is your Management.java in desktop

Comment: @singhakash Yes I did