# Class names, 'Introductions', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested

Tags: java, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I got this error messaje while trying to copile a simple Java program. I know there is this question already here on Stack but the solution(that i forgot to include the .java suffixwhen compiling the program) still doesn't work for me. This is the program:

```
import java.io.Console;

    public class Introductions {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Console console = System.console();
            // Welcome to the Introductions program!  Your code goes below here
            String firstName = "Paul";
            console.printf("Hello, my name is %s\n", firstName);
            console.printf("%s this is learning how to write Java\n", firstName);
      }
    }
```

Comment: What command are you using to compile the program?

Comment: 'javac Introductions.java' to compile it, and then 'javac Introductions' to run it

Comment: You need to use `java` to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different commands to compile Java programs and run Java programs.  You're receiving an error that means that the command to compile the program (`javac`) has received arguments that don't include the .java suffix, as mentioned in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063266/javac-error-class-names-are-only-accepted-if-annotation-processing-is-explicitl) about this error.

It sounds, however, like you are compiling correctly, using `javac Introductions.java`.  Your problem is actually in the second step, running the program.  Running `javac Introductions` tells Java you want to compile again, and so it correctly points out that you forgot the extension.

But you're not wanting to compile a second time; you want to run it!  That uses `java` instead of `javac`.

To compile: `javac Introductions.java`

To run: `java Introductions`

See also [How do I run a Java program from the command line on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows) (though this isn't really Windows-specific).