# "NoClassDefFoundError" when running .jar file with cmd

Tags: java, javac, noclassdeffounderror

So I have two files to compile into jar file: `Testfield.class` (which i make from `Testfield.java` via javac command) and `manifest.txt`.

Now I'm getting this `noclassdeffounderror` when im running my jar file in cmd
it goes as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: Testfield (wrong name: testfield/Testfield)
```

What's the deal ?

edit*
Testfield.class file contains the following line:

```
Main-Class: Testfield
```

Comment: A manifest’s `Main-Class` attribute contains a *class name,* not a file name.  It must not contain “.class”.

Comment: tried both, the same result happens

Comment: Does Testfield.java contain a `package` declaration?

Comment: yes, "package Testfield {...}

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code for the Testfield class.

Answer (score 0):

The NoClassDefFoundError indicates that the classloader (in this case java.net.URLClassLoader), which is responsible for dynamically loading classes, cannot find the .class file for the class that you're trying to use can you post your manifest?

You can also try to run javac in `-verbose`

Comment: you can also try to run javac in -verbose

Comment: it throws "Class names, Testfield.jar, are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063266/javac-error-class-names-are-only-accepted-if-annotation-processing-is-explicitl