# Full form of .cpp extension

Tags: c++

What is the full form of .cpp extension?
Is it **c** **p**lus **p**lus or **c** **p**re**p**rocessor?

Comment: The `.cpp` extension is meant to stand for "c plus plus". Independently, many compiler distributions include a program named `cpp`, for `c preprocessor`. This pre-dates the invention of C++.

Answer (score 2):

File extensions have no intrinsic meaning. You can name a source file `xyzzy.abc` and still compile it as C++ code. Just as you can take a MS Word document and name it `foo.bar` and it's still a Word document. Extensions mean nothing apart from being helpful hints.
`foo.exe` renamed to `xxx.xy1` is still the same file with the same contents.

Comment: Can I ~~compile~~ a c++ code as foo.bar and not foo.bar.cpp ?  Edit: I meant saved instead of compiled.

Comment: is it really possible to compile a file named xyzzy.abc as c++ 's source code ? how about this post :: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063266/javac-error-class-names-are-only-accepted-if-annotation-processing-is-explicitl

Comment: @AyushBasak You can compile a file as C++ code no matter what the file name is. The file name doesn't *matter*.

Comment: to add: it's always required extension to make compilation successful, i glad to know the reason behind of your answer @jesper

Comment: @Papai "is it really possible to compile a file named xyzzy.abc as c++ 's source code ?" - Yes.

Comment: I understand extension names don't matter, but since people use the common '.cpp' extension, it should be some mnemonic. For example .xls is a mnemonic of Excel.

Comment: @AyushBasak It shouldn't *be* anything, it doesn't *have to* mean anything. It's just a convention. It does happen that the .cpp convention matches nicely with C Plus Plus, but it didn't *have to*. Many code bases also use ".cc" or ".C" (note the upper case), for C++ code.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks. I understand now. I was kind of confused because I had seen some people claim that .cpp officially stands for c plus plus.

Comment: @AyushBasak "officially stands for" - according to whom? Who is "the official" ?

Comment: @JesperJuhl nvm about that. But does it mean I can choose any random extension for a c++ source code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220275/discussion-between-ayush-basak-and-jesper-juhl).

Answer (score 1):

> What is the full form of .cpp extension?

There is no specification for this. It means whatever the author who wrote it means with it. When I write a c++ source file and give it a name ending in .cpp, **I** mean C plus plus.

Given that C pre processor doesn't convey meaning of C++ source file, and given that build systems generally assume .cpp to imply C++, it is reasonable to assume that those build systems do not interpret .cpp to mean C pre processor.

P.S. Another common suffix for C++ source files is .c++, which should be unambiguous. Yet another is .cxx where the plusses have fallen over. It is sometimes used by people who worry that + might not be valid in a file name.

Comment: `.C` and `.cc` are also common.